# How to hide the keyboard in flutter when tapping outside of the TextField without triggering any other actions?

Tags: flutter

Hi I have the following (simplified) code:

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).focusedChild?.unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("Button pressed!");
              },
              child: Text("Click me"),
            ),
            TextField(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code results in the following UI:

[image]

When I click on the blue button, "Button pressed!" gets printed and the keyboard does not disappear.
The problem here, is that this behavior is not what I want. I want that the keyboard disappears when I click somewhere outside of the `TextField`, and that the button does not get triggered, even when I directly click on it. So for example if I click on the button just the keyboard should disappear without any other action/side effect (nothing gets printed in this case). But it should still be possible to interact with the `TextField` normally.

*Note: Disabling the button is not a good option since in my real case scenario the page is build out of a lot complex widgets and disabling them is really complicated.*

Already stuck there for a while now. Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 8):

Use the onTapOutside method that TextField provides:

```
onTapOutside: (PointerDownEvent event) {
   FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
},
```

Answer (score 7):

Wrap the Scaffold with Gesture detector and on tap unfocus the focus scope

example

```dart
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: const Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing this the button still triggers the action. In my scenario, where the TextField is focused and the keyboard is visible I want to be able to tap outside of the TextField (even on the button) WITHOUT triggering the action on the button. (Please note: Since the real use case is way more complex just disabling each button one by one is a option I want to avoid)

Comment: well, if you click on the button it will fire its own function rather that the parent function.

Answer (score 2):

I also needed to hide the keyboard when I clicked on a date picker (another widget)

During my experience, with GestureDetector keyboard hid itself when I clicked somewhere that is not a widget. It would not hide itself otherwise.

Simply changing `GestureDetector`
to
`Listener` and adding

`onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),` gave me the solution.

So, in your instance, what you should do is, wrap the Button "Click me" with a `Listener` and give it `onPointerDown` ,that should hide your keyboard whenever you press the button.

Comment: But it still trigger the action

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextField(
          onTapOutside: (PointerDownEvent event) {
            FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
          },
          maxLines: 4,
          controller: commentController,
          style: black14MediumTextStyle,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 14.0),
            hintText: 'Engage with your opions or comments..',
            hintStyle: grey14RegularTextStyle,
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
        )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your Scaffold Widget in a Button it can be Gesture Detector or Inkwell. Then add unfocus method in it.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
  child: const Scaffold(
  body: TextFormField(
   decoration: OutlineInputBorder()),
);
```

Comment: Same answer as @SuzZan, but not what I want